# Conditional filter in WHERE clause

Tags: sql

How can I set a conditional filter in a SQL WHERE clause?  For example, I have a parameter @ID with the following procedure

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Column1 = 'test' AND Column2 = @ID
```

However, If @ID = -1 I don't want the last part of the SQL (AND Column2 = @ID) included

I realize I can make an if statement with 2 separate queries, however this is a large script and has this same issue multiple times, so I was hoping there was a better way than nearly duplicating several queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ok for T-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Column1 = 'test' AND (@ID = -1 OR Column2 = @ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just include the condition in your SQL as an OR, note the brackets

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Column1 = 'test' AND (@ID = -1 OR Column2 = @ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Column1 = 'test' AND @ID in (-1,Column2)
```